# R programming: when I run the following code, I am wondering why my rand vector always stays as a zero vector?

Tags: r

```
    M1 <- 1.69683*0.424

    "g2" <- function(u)
    {x<-0.1*tan(pi*u*1.5)+0.9465}

    "g" <- function(x)
      {(1/(1.69683*pi*(0.1^2+(x-0.9465)^2)))}



    n<-10
    rand <- rep(0,n)



i <- 1
    count <- 0

    while(i<=n)
    {u <- runif(1)
     u1 <- runif(1)
     x <- g2(u)
     f<-exp(-0.5*(-2+log(x/(1-x)))^2)/(x*(1-x))
     if(m*g(x)*u1<=f)
     {rand[i] <- x
       i <- i+1
     }
     else count <- count+1
     }
```

Also I always get this error message, could someone explain why?

Error in if (m * g(x) * u1 <= f) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In log(x/(1 - x)) : NaNs produced

thanks!

Comment: Where is `m` defined? I suspect your only real problem is that error message, which is probably related to `m`'s definition.

Comment: sorry m is suppose to be M1 and even so i still get the same error.
Julian, im editing my rand vector in my while loop, it should change

Comment: Sounds like you need some debugging tips.  Try taking it out of the loop and running it line by line.  Where do you get the error?  (Hint: it's in the log(x/(1-x)), as the error message tells you.) Try setting `u <- 0.35` and see what happens.

Comment: Aaron i can see that for u <- 0.35 it doesnt work but i cant spot the mistake... could you tell me what it is pls? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function `g2(u)` has asymptotes at u = 1/3 and 1, so `g2` can take on values >1. Since you set:

```
 x <- g2(u)
 f<-exp(-0.5*(-2+log(x/(1-x)))^2)/(x*(1-x))
```

`f` is undefined (NAN) when `g2 > 1`, and this causes the following `if` statement to fail with the error you are getting.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but generally you should plot your functions first to see how they behave. For example,

```
z <- seq(0,.999,.001)
plot(z,g2(z), type="l")
```

would have shown you right away that `g2 >1` under some circumstances.